# Change key to true then show view in swift

Tags: swift

OK, so I've added a view onto my Application that asks the user to accept or decline the Terms of Service. I have it so when they click accept, it changes the key "TermsAccepted" to true. If they close the app, and re-open it, it gives them access. However I'd like to be able to give them access without re-opening the app first.

So in my ViewController (Main Screen), in my viewDidLoad I have the following:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("TermsAccepted") {
  // They've been accepted, do nothing.
} else {
  let termsView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstLaunchTerms") as! FirstLaunchTermsView
  self.presentViewController(termsView, animated: true, completion: null
}
```

In the 'LaunchTermsView' I have the following code for when they accept the terms.

```
@IBAction func acceptTerms(sender : AnyObject)
 {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "TermsAccepted")
 }
```

And thi works fine, but they have to re-open the application.

I tried to just have it so the button opens the Main View at the same time as those terms are accepted (After the key is updated) but it gives me the following error.

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

I assumed this meant that it was wanting to re-open the launch terms view again, so I tried to move all the code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear so it checks each time, but it just gives the same error. (it was a long shot try before I posted on here).

I had a look at some posts on here, but a lot of them were in ObjC or just didn't give me a solution or any form of help to trying to find one myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're presenting your terms view controller you should simply be able to dismiss it when you're done with it. You don't show any other code so I'm assuming that your 'home' view controller is waiting to be revealed underneath (you don't need to try to show it again).

Comment: So the Main Controller is the initial view, so I assume that would mean it's just waiting to be revealed underneath? I tried 'self.dismissViewControllerAnimated' but that just gave me the same error as well, which was quite weird.

Comment: Nevermind! I forgot to remove the link from the accept button on the terms and the Main View from my previous bad attempt at linking. Thank you Wain! I don't know why you saying 'Dismiss' jogged something into my mind, but thank you. :D